# How to check if a value in a numeric field is an integer?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a numeric column in Postgresql with these values:

```
1.0
3.5
1.5
4.0
```

I want to write a query which will give me all rows that aren't integer.
Meaning I want to get:

```
3.5
1.5
```

How do I do that?

Comment: where numcol <> cast(numcol as int)

Comment: Be aware that you can only rely on an integer check with precise data types such as DECIMAL. With an approximate data type like REAL you can't (or at least you'd have to define a tolerance).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use modulo division:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col DECIMAL(10,2));

INSERT INTO tab(col)
VALUES (1.0),(3.5),(1.5),(4.0);

SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col % 1 <> 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387548)**</kbd>

[`Remainder`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder):

> In mathematics, the remainder is the amount "left over" after
>   performing some computation.

For example:

```
10 % 4 = 2      because (FLOOR(10/4)  = 2,  2 * 4 + 2 = 10)
13 % 4 = 1      because (FLOOR(13/4)  = 3,  3 * 4 + 1 = 13)
3.5 % 1 = 0.5   because (FLOOR(3.5/1) = 3, 3 * 1 + 0.5 = 3.5)
4.0 % 1 = 0     because (FLOOR(4.0/1) = 4, 4 * 1 + 0 = 4)
```

So if number has something else than zeros after decimal point you know that it is not Integer.

Alternatively you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col <> FLOOR(col);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387944)**</kbd>

Comment: can you explain the where?

Comment: excellent answer, I now see the relationship between floor and mod with remainders of zero.

Comment: Your final solution worked for me, because postgres didn't recognize the `%` operator but did recognize `FLOOR`.

Comment: @autonopy it a very old postgresql bug where % operator doesn't work. You should upgrade your postgresql.

Comment: @SüniÚr "very old"? I'm on v12.

Comment: yes imo 5 years old versions are old especially if they contains annoying bugs. Currently postgresql latest version is 16.2